# Can I pass parameter from Kendo Grid making call to Html.DropDownList

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.options)
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@
        class = "Class"
    })
    .Columns(columns = > {
        columns
            .Bound(c = > c.Name)
            .Filterable(false)
            .ClientTemplate("<span title=\"#=Description#\">#=Name#</span>");
        columns
            .Bound(c = > c.Default)
            .Filterable(false)
            .ClientTemplate("<fieldset  data-avl=\"#=Available#\"  data-dependent=\"#=Dependent#\">" +
                "<span class=\"select\">" + * * //Call here with model property as a parameter
                Html.DropDownList("options[__id__][Default]", TestFR.Client.Models.Data.Getoption("#=Name#")).ToString() + * *
                Html.Hidden("options[__id__][Name]", "#=Name#").ToString() +
                "</fieldset>"
        );
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource = > dataSource
        .Ajax()` enter code here`
        .Model(model = > {
            model.Id(item = > item.Name);
            model.Field(item = > item.Default).Editable(true);
        })))
```

Comment: Pass Property #=Name# as a parameter in Html.DropDownList("options[__id__][Default]", TestFR.Client.Models.Data.Getoption("#=Name#")).ToString()

Comment: I can use Model.options[0].Name but how do i access the index